# How to make image background transparent?

Tags: image, imagemagick

I have two images:

[First](http://www.eurocopter.in/contest/images/loader33.gif)

http://www.eurocopter.in/contest/images/loader33.gif

[Second](https://studentwebhosting.com/media/uploads/animated-web-preloader.gif)

[image]

If you will see the first image has no background. So the background looks white. The second image has black background.

- Question 1 : What we call first type of picture?
- Question 2 : How to make that type of picture?
- Question 3 : How to transform the second type of picture into the first type of picture?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are *animated GIFs*, the first with transparent background. You can separate the image into individual frames with ImageMagick (installed on most Linux distros and available for free for OSX and Linux) like this:

```
convert -coalesce type1.gif frame%02d.gif
```

which will give you the following 18 frames as individual images

```
frame00.gif frame04.gif frame08.gif frame12.gif frame16.gif
frame01.gif frame05.gif frame09.gif frame13.gif frame17.gif
frame02.gif frame06.gif frame10.gif frame14.gif
frame03.gif frame07.gif frame11.gif frame15.gif
```

**frame00.gif**

[image]

You can see them all at once if you make them into a montage like this:

```
convert -coalesce type1.gif miff:- | montage -tile x4 -frame 5 - montage.gif
```

[image]

You can find information about each frame, such as its size like this:

```
identify type1.gif

type1.gif[0] GIF 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 128c 29.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
type1.gif[1] GIF 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 128c 29.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
type1.gif[2] GIF 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 128c 29.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
type1.gif[3] GIF 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 64c 29.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
type1.gif[4] GIF 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 128c 29.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
type1.gif[5] GIF 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 128c 29.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
type1.gif[6] GIF 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 64c 29.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
type1.gif[7] GIF 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 128c 29.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
type1.gif[8] GIF 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 128c 29.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
type1.gif[9] GIF 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 128c 29.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
type1.gif[10] GIF 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 64c 29.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
type1.gif[11] GIF 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 128c 29.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
type1.gif[12] GIF 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 128c 29.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
type1.gif[13] GIF 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 128c 29.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
type1.gif[14] GIF 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 64c 29.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
type1.gif[15] GIF 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 64c 29.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
type1.gif[16] GIF 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 128c 29.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
type1.gif[17] GIF 100x100 100x100+0+0 8-bit sRGB 128c 29.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

You can put all the frames back together like this:

```
convert frame* -loop 0 -delay 20 anim.gif
```

[image]

You can try and remove the black background from the second one to make it more like the first one, using a command like this. You may need to fiddle with the `fuzz` factor a bit:

```
convert type2.gif -fuzz 15% -transparent black new.gif
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yesw, you can, you have to use some sort of Photo Editing software like Photoshop, try to follow the steps in this guide, let me know how it goes.

[How to Create a Transparent GIF in Photoshop](http://www.mediacollege.com/adobe/photoshop/transparent/gif.html)